# In which case recvfrom a UDP socket returns -1 but errno is 0?

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming

Does anyone knows that in which case recvfrom a UDP socket returns -1 but errno is 0 ?

Answer (score 1):

The case where you call some other function that sets `errno` to zero after `recvfrom` returns. This is surprisingly easy to do. To be safe, copy `errno` to some other variable *immediately* after `recvfrom` returns.

Wrong:

```
i = recvfrom (...);
if (i < 0)
{
     printf ("recvfrom error!\n");
     printf ("errno=%d\n", errno);
}
```

What happens if the first `printf` modifies `errno`?

Right:

```
i = recvfrom (...);
if (i < 0)
{
     int j = errno;
     printf ("recvfrom error!\n");
     printf ("errno=%d\n", j);
}
```

The ANSI spec says, "[A] program that uses errno for error checking should ... inspect it before a subsequent library function call."

Comment: Well corrected, I was about to pounce. But surely it would be more to the point to reverse the order of the `printf()` calls, or to combine them?

Answer (score 1):

Never. That should not happen.